# The proxy requires username, password issue in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, proxy, google-chrome-extensions

From the past day, I'm getting this new error asking to enter some username and password for the proxy when I'm trying to use a VPN extension inside chrome (Zenmate VPN, SetupVPN) and even do a small google search.

I'm using the latest chrome build Version 72.0.3626.109

[image: Image of the Error]

I've tried a few solutions stated on the internet like clearing cache and cookies but still, it keeps popping up.

Answer (score 0):

I messaged them about this earlier and they got back to me with the following response:

> Hi there,
>
> Thank you for getting back to us.
>
> Our developers are now aware of the issue and are currently working on resolving it. We, therefore, kindly ask you for your patience since we will need a little more time.
>
> In the meantime, you can try these temporary solutions:
>
> Reinstall the app.
> Clear caché and cookies.
> Try with a different browser.
>
> We are really thankful for your understanding and patience.
>
> All the best,

I'm temped to say they know about the issue but need to fix it because the the new updated version of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that if I miss company-proxy prompt like this by e.g. dismissing it my mistake - I need to restart my PC (ubuntu) in order to trigger this dialog and be able to access the site.
Anyone knows how to actually (re-)trigger this dialog?